# Keras input dimension

Tags: python, theano, keras

I'm struggling with formatting my data.

I designed a simple model in Keras.
It consists of two separate models (`Embedding` layer and `LSTM` layer).
Those two models are then merges with `Merge`. They are then combined together by some convolution layers.

Those are my embedded example sentences.

```
x1
>>> array([[ 0, 25,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
y1
>>> array([[42, 10,  0,  0,  0, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

Using `predict` I get desired single output for the combined sentences.

```
model.predict([x1,y1])
>>> array([[ 0.92327869]])
```

I can even use

```
model.fit([x,y],gold[0])
```

to train the model, where

```
gold[0]
>>> array([ 1.])
```

**The question is** how can I format examples `x_i` and `y_i` so that I can use it in fit function. `model.predict([[x1,x2],[y1,y2]])` didn't work, yields

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following the Keras [Embedding](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) documentation you need to provide as an input to Embedding layer a `numpy.array` of dimension 2. Because you have a multiple inputs - you need to provide a list of numpy arrays in order to feed them to multiple inputs.

In the last case however your are feeding a list of lists of inputs. This caused a problem. In order to solve this you need to [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) these two arrays by:

```
x = numpy.concatenate((x1, x2), axis = 0)
y = numpy.concatenate((y1, y2), axis = 0)
```